# Get position of selected document in collection [mongoDB]

Tags: mongodb, collections, find, position

How to get position (index) of selected document in mongo collection?

E.g.
this document: `db.myCollection.find({"id":12345})`
has index `3` in `myCollection`

```
myCollection:
    id: 12340, name: 'G'
    id: 12343, name: 'V'
    id: 12345, name: 'A'
    id: 12348, name: 'N'
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If your requirement is to find the position of the document irrespective of any order, that is not 
possible as MongoDb does not store the documents in specific order.
However,if you want to know the index based on some field, say `_id` , you can use this method.

If you are strictly following auto increments in your `_id` field. You can count all the documents
that have value less than that `_id`, say n , then n + 1 would be index of the document based on `_id`.

```
n = db.myCollection.find({"id": { "$lt" : 12345}}).count() ;
```

This would also be valid if documents are deleted from the collection.

Comment: I personally use this `db.collection.find({_id: {$lte: ObjectId("12345")}}).count()` command to get the position... I mean less than equal is more specific to this.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no single command to do this, and this is impossible in general case (see Derick's answer). However, using `count()` for a query done on an ordered id value field seems to work. **Warning: this assumes that there is a reliably ordered field, which is difficult to achieve in a concurrent writer case. In this example `_id` is used, however this will only work with a single writer case.**:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.1
connecting to: test
> use so_test
switched to db so_test
> db.example.insert({name: 'A'})
> db.example.insert({name: 'B'})
> db.example.insert({name: 'C'})
> db.example.insert({name: 'D'})
> db.example.insert({name: 'E'})
> db.example.insert({name: 'F'})
> db.example.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fc5f040fb359c680edf1a7b"), "name" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fc5f046fb359c680edf1a7c"), "name" : "B" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fc5f04afb359c680edf1a7d"), "name" : "C" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fc5f04dfb359c680edf1a7e"), "name" : "D" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fc5f050fb359c680edf1a7f"), "name" : "E" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fc5f053fb359c680edf1a80"), "name" : "F" }
> db.example.find({_id: ObjectId("4fc5f050fb359c680edf1a7f")})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fc5f050fb359c680edf1a7f"), "name" : "E" }
> db.example.find({_id: {$lte: ObjectId("4fc5f050fb359c680edf1a7f")}}).count()
5
>
```

This should also be fairly fast if the queried field is indexed. The example is in mongo shell, but `count()` should be available in all driver libs as well.

Answer (score 3):

This might be very slow but straightforward method. Here you can pass as usual query. Just I am looping all the documents and checking if condition to match the record. Here I am checking with _id field. You can use any other single field or multiple fields to check it.

```
var docIndex = 0;
db.url_list.find({},{"_id":1}).forEach(function(doc){
  docIndex++;
  if("5801ed58a8242ba30e8b46fa"==doc["_id"]){
    print('document position is...' + docIndex);
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: This is not the questions answer but it solved my problem..Thanx

Comment: It is the answer and the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that MongoDB can return this as it does not keep documents in order in the database, just like MySQL f.e. doesn't name row numbers.

The ObjectID trick from jhonkola will only work if only one client creates new elements, as the ObjectIDs are generated on the client side, with the first part being a timestamp. There is no guaranteed order if different clients talk to the same server. Still, I would not rely on this.

I also don't quite understand what you are trying to do though, so perhaps mention that in your question? I can then update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for notifying about the _id problem, the answer was modified.

Comment: I'm having the same requirement, in my case, I need to know a user's position ordering by score and also, if the user is in position 13,500, get from 13,450 to 13,550 so the user has some context on his ranking.

Also, the count solution is a really slow one for lower rankings, because, as you know, count will have to go through all of the documents that match the query, if my collection is ordered by score I have 10,000,000 users, and need to get the position of the 9,999,500th user, it will have to count practically all the collection.  Does anyone has any other ideas?

Comment: @jmdiego, did you ever find a working solution for the problem you describe? I need to have the position of a cursor based result.

Comment: Just do a query that get all the results that greater than or lower than your value, and count it.

Answer (score 0):

Restructure your collection to include the position of any entry i.e {'id': 12340, 'name': 'G', 'position': 1} then when searching the database collection(myCollection) using the desired position as a query

Answer (score 0):

The queries I use that return the entire collection all use sort to get a reproducible order, find.sort.forEach works with the script above to get the correct index.