# How to know which document I have selected [mongodb]

Tags: angular, mongodb, typescript

Well. There's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813908/get-position-of-selected-document-in-collection-mongodb) on stackoveflow. But the accepted answer is different from my coding and my way of implementing CRUD operations. The accepted answer says implenet this code: `n = db.myCollection.find({"id": { "$lt" : 12345}}).count(); Whwre 12345 is _id value(say).` I want to read all the records from my mongodb collection and there's a 'Read more' button associated with each record which will retrieve other properties of that particular record. Its ablog kind of thing. First `title` i showed and then on click event `content` will be displayed. Its an angular 8 project. Here is a sample record.

```
_id: 5d74ef062a407b0bac6bfff0
title: "Making a plum pie"
content: "You need lots of plum for that"
```

The `_id` field is auto generated. If only it was `integer` type and autoincreented, my job would be done. Anyway. Hers my code.

**articles.component.html**

```
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-3" *ngFor="let article of articles">
    <div class="card text-center">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{article.title}}</h5>
        <a (click)="onPress(article._id)" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="data-container">
  <h3>Content will be displayed here</h3>
</div>
```

**articles.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ArticleService } from '../article.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-articles',
  templateUrl: './articles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./articles.component.css']
})
export class ArticlesComponent implements OnInit {

  articles = []
  constructor(private _articleService: ArticleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._articleService.getArticles()
    .subscribe(
      res => this.articles = res,
      err => console.log(err)
    )
  }

  //HERE I AM DISPLAYING MORE CONTENT   
  onPress(id) {
    this._articleService.getArticles()
    .subscribe (
      data => {
        console.log(data.content);
        document.querySelector('#data-container').innerHTML=data[0].content;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Here I know I should not hard code the index `data[0].content`. But `_id` is not an `integer` value. Then what should i pass here.

Here is my **article.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ArticleService {
  private _articlesUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/articles";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getArticles() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this._articlesUrl)
  }
}
```

Please help me. I have found a solution but I dont know how to use it.
`n = db.myCollection.find({"id": { "$lt" : 12345}}).count();`
Whwre `12345` is `_id` value(say).

Comment: It's unclear based on your question which part of the linked question/answer was unclear, and you've provided frontend code snippets that aren't useful to trying to help with a backend coding problem. Adding details about what your backend looks like & what you've tried to get the count would help people answer the question

Comment: You need to make backend changes to the server that's providing these mongo documents by counting the # of documents in the collection. Looking at the frontend code won't help at all

Comment: Ok. What is `db` and `myCollection` in `n = db.myCollection.find({"id": { "$lt" : id}}).count();` Thats why i said. I am not implementing any of these.
`

Comment: Are you trying to sort your records?

Comment: @WillAlexander No. Sorting isn't required. So i am not implementing that. I just want to know the index number of document that i have selected.

Comment: What do you mean by index number?

Comment: @WillAlexander I am getting the whole bunch of objects as an array.

0: Object { _id: "5d7491dc1c9d440000076426", title: "How to make a tea", content: "Take a Pan. Put some water." }
​
1: Object { _id: "5d74ef062a407b0bac6bfff0", title: "Making a plum pie", content: "You need lots of plum for that" }
​
2: Object { _id: "5d7502af2a407b0bac6bfff1", title: "How to install Atom editor on Ubuntu 18.04", content: "<p>You can download it form the official website</p>" }

Comment: See @willis thats why i gave the front end code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No worries! I misunderstood what you were asking. Glad you were able to find help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* what you're looking for is something along these lines:

```html
<div class="col-md-4 mb-3" *ngFor="let article of articles; let i = index;">
...
  <a (click)="onPress(i)" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
```

That would allow you to grab the article directly from the Array you already have.

However, I feel obligated to point out that your entire structure here goes against Angular best practices, and needs revising. Try going through the tutorial in the Angular docs; it is very well structured.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks and sure I will follow what you said about best practices in Angular