# How to find the index of a element in a sorted set of documents in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In mongodb how can I get the position of a element in a sorted list of documents?

E.g: If I have 4 students with scores. I want to sort these documents by score and then get the position of John. Result should be 3 in following example.

```
Name Score
Paul  4
Sam   5
John  7
Ron   20
```

I tried to use count but it didn't work with:

```
User.find({ "name": "john"}).count()
```

[[Get position of selected document in collection [mongoDB] ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813908/get-position-of-selected-document-in-collection-mongodb) This other question doesn't give any answer for this question, its a different question even-though titles are similar.

Comment: What you missed was the suggested solution was to obtain the `count()` of documents "less than" the target or "matched" document under the sort conditions. Which would be "less than" the specific value in this case, and less "less than John" would not make any sense. Hence why the answer you looked at already had a numeric value.

Comment: I may also note that this same question was [previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58760905/get-position-of-selected-document-in-a-sorted-collection-in-mongodb?noredirect=1#58760905) and marked as a duplicate of the linked question mentioned. Instead of reposting the question, if you think a duplicate does not answer the question, then please edit your original question instead. You did that, but as a "repost" instead of an "edit'. A simple edit will give you the same response, pointing out what you missed. And still answers your question.