# Assign an incremental number to a field in a MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB aggregation and each document has a field (groupNumber) like this:

[image]

I need that each groupNumber has a different number for each document (could be incremental 1,2,3..)

Most of the solutions that I had found are using "find" [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813908/get-position-of-selected-document-in-collection-mongodb) , but I think that cannot be used in an aggregation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a lookup, but I don't think it will scale well.  I would think this should be persisted in some way, perhaps `$out` to another collection, so that the numbers are stable and deleting or inserting a document won't change the numbers for any other group.

```
db.target.aggregate([
    {"$lookup":{
        "from":"target",
        "as":"looked",
        "let":{"srcId":"$_id"},
        "pipeline":[
          {"$match":{"$expr":{"$lte":["$_id","$$srcId"]}}},
          {"$group":{"_id":"null", "cnt":{"$sum":1}}}
        ]
    }},
    {"$addFields":{"groupNumber":{"$arrayElemAt":["$looked.cnt",0]}}},
    {"$project":{"looked":0}}
])
```