# How to update a field in a MongoDB collection so it increments linearly

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've been struggling with mongodb for some time now, and the idea is quite simple: I have a collection, and I want o to add a new ID field. This field is controlled by our API, and it auto increments it for each new document inserted.

The thing is, the collection already has some documents, so I must initialize each document with a number sequentially, no matter the order:

```
collection: holiday {
'date': date,
'name': string
}
```

The collection has 12 documents, so each document should get an ID property, with values from 1 to 12. What kind of query or function should I use to do this? No restrictions so far, and performance is not a problem.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with an update, but you could use aggregation as described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60306497/assign-an-incremental-number-to-a-field-in-a-mongodb-aggregation/60309530#60309530 and output that to  a new collection.

Comment: You can try this from _Mongo Shell_ (assuming that  there are 12 documents in your collection): `newId = 0; db.collection.find().forEach( doc => db.collection.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { ID: ++newId } } ) );`. This will assign a new field called as `ID` for each of the 12 documents, with the `ID` values from 1 to 12.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not optimal but works :)

```
var newId = 1;
var oldIds = [];
db.holiday.find().forEach(it => {   
    const documentToMigrate = it;
    oldIds.push(it._id);
    documentToMigrate._id = newId;
    db.holiday.save(documentToMigrate);
    ++newId;
})

db.holiday.remove({_id: {$in: oldIds}});
```